# Can adjectives be followed by genitive?

Tags: grammar, possessives

A dirty man’s job - (A job for a dirty man).

A dirty, man’s job - (Would that be correct? I want to say that it is a dirty job for men (man)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say that the first phrase ("a dirty man's job") is actually just ambiguous between a job for a dirty man and a dirty job for a man. However, I agree that your interpretation is the most likely one, hence the need for a different way to say this.

"A dirty, man's job" is not correct, but there are a few ways you could express this. For example,

> A dirty, manly job
>
> A man's dirty job
>
> A man's job and a dirty job
>
> A dirty job for men

In short, in cases like this you need to rephrase to make it unambiguous.

As an aside, I will say that this is one case where I think you would be *understood* using the incorrect form. In my opinion it would be acceptable to write "a dirty, man's job" in highly informal communication such as a text message to a friend.

Comment: Why is the first one ambiguous? I thought that the indefinite article and the apostrophe make it clear that it is  “a dirty man” and his job.

Comment: Dirty could be modifying "man" or it could be modifying the entire noun phrase "man's job". It might be clearer with an example in context. Say the adjective is "lucrative" instead of "dirty" and consider the sentence "It's a man's job, and quite a lucrative man's job." In this case "lucrative" is used often to describe jobs but almost never to describe men. It's still technically ambiguous, but now I'd lean more towards interpreting it as saying the "man's job" is lucrative. In your example I do think it sounds more like it's modifying just "man".

Comment: Interesting. But why then articles cannot be used in front of names (The Einsten’s paper), when I could say they modify the whole phrase? I was taught in this case “the” would modify the name only.

Comment: Articles are a little different because they aren't "modifying" a noun. A good rule of thumb is that you can't use an article when there's a possessive. So "Einstein's paper says..." or "The Einstein paper says..." are both fine.  There are exceptions, for example you could say "the St. Elmo's fire". That's because the whole phrase "St. Elmo's fire" is the name of a phenomenon.

Comment: But I believe I have seen the definite article used in nouns and genitive when they refer to things. Or am I mistaken? Something like” the company’s profit” or “the dog’s bone”

Comment: Yes, I misspoke. I meant that in the case of a possessive that the article almost always relates only to the first noun ("the company," "the dog").